# Is it possible to debug a Gitlab CI build interactively?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a build in Gitlab CI that takes a long time (10mins+) to run, and it's very annoying to wait for the entire process every time I need to experiment / make changes. It seems like surely there's a way to access some sort of shell during the build process and run commands interactively instead of placing them all in a deploy script.

I know it's possible to run Gitlab CI *tests* locally, but I can't seem to find a way to access the deploy running in process, even after scouring the docs.

Am I out of luck or is there a way to manually control this lengthy build?

Comment: as long as you're using docker images, you can still run your jobs locally (see e.g. https://bryce.fisher-fleig.org/blog/faster-ci-debugging-with-gitlabci/index.html for some complete reference) and restart the containers/inspect them (i.e. with `docker logs`) upon failure

Comment: Have you ever found a solutions to this? I have to test the integration of my builds with a Kubernetes cluster connected via their proprietary panel so local builds don't really help here. I've always done it on https://travis-ci.com/ so I just assumed I could do it with GitLab too. Apparently I was wrong `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @FrancescoCasula I am sorry to say I still have not solved this issue. If I come across a fix I will absolutely update the thread.

Answer (score 7):

I have not found a clean way for now, but here is how I do it

1. I start building locally `gitlab-runner exec docker your_build_name`
2. I kill `gitlab-runner` using `control + c` right after the docker image to be built. You can still add the command `sleep 1m` as the first script line just to have time enough to kill `gitlab-runner`
   Note: gitlab-runner will create a docker and then delete it once the job is done… killing it will ensure the docker is still there - [no other alternative I know for now…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34873368/how-can-i-save-the-docker-container-that-was-used-to-perform-a-build-in-gitlab-c).
3. Manually log into the container `docker exec -i -t <instance-id/tag-name> bash`
4. Run your script commands manually…

Comment: This approach works for me but notice that jobs are built under /builds within the container so after executing `docker exec -i -t <instance-id/tag-name> bash` you should run `cd /builds/project-0/` an there you will find the job root.

Comment: What do you mean by 'your_build_name'? I have successfully installed and registed the gitlab-runner in my local machine.